# Simplest way to sort html table content

Tags: html-parsing

Given content from http://packdeps.haskellers.com/reverse what is the easiest way to represent content of this table sorted by second column? What tools are best for this kind of job?

Since content looked simple, I tried to hack with tr, sed and awk (mainly to learn the tools) but it turned out to be too complex to get all rows right. Format could look like this:

```
47 strict
54 Win32
55 transformers-base
57 enumerator
68 system-filepath
69 xml
```

or any other format as long it is not making for further processing too complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), and just for learning I did the job using the `Web::Scraper` module. It uses `CSS` selectors to extract both columns of the table and sorts them by the second one, which indicates the number of dependencias for each package:

The `script.pl` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Web::Scraper;
use URI;

die qq|Usage: perl $0 <url>\n| unless @ARGV == 1;

my $packages_deps = scraper {
        process 'tr', 'package_deps[]' => scraper {
                process 'td:first-child > a', 'package_name' => 'TEXT';
                process 'td:nth-child(2)', 'tot_deps' => 'TEXT';
        };  
        result 'package_deps';
};

my $response = $packages_deps->scrape( URI->new( shift ) );
for ( sort { $a->{tot_deps} <=> $b->{tot_deps} } @$response[1..$#$response] ) { 
        printf qq|%d %s\n|, $_->{tot_deps}, $_->{package_name};
}
```

Run it providing the url:

```
perl script.pl "http://packdeps.haskellers.com/reverse"
```

And it yields (only show the beginning and end part of the list):

```
1 abstract-par-accelerate
1 accelerate-fft
1 acme-year
1 action-permutations
1 active
1 activehs-base
...
766 text
794 filepath
796 transformers
915 directory
1467 mtl
1741 bytestring
1857 containers
5287 base
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript includes a native sorting function, so Javascript is a natural choice.

There is a simple script here which you can either use or examine and learn from:

http://www.allmyscripts.com/Table_Sort/